# How to perform partial inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance

I have two classes for example:

```
class Parent(object):

    def hello(self):
        print 'Hello world'

    def goodbye(self):
        print 'Goodbye world'


class Child(Parent):
    pass
```

class Child must inherit only hello() method from Parent and and there should be no mention of goodbye().
Is it possible ?

ps yes, I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647118/is-it-possible-to-do-partial-inheritance-with-python)

Important NOTE: And I can modify only Child class (in the parent class of all possible should be left as is)

Comment: Could you elaborate on what is unsatisfactory with the answer given there?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to do partial inheritance with Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647118/is-it-possible-to-do-partial-inheritance-with-python)

Comment: It's technically possible (with a few dirty hacks), but it's a sure design smell. What's your real use case ?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams See postscript um

Comment: adding to bruno: check out [How to inherit only a small part of methods from a large class?](https://www.sololearn.com/Discuss/1314620/how-to-inherit-only-a-small-part-of-methods-from-a-large-class-a-into-a-new-class-b-without). Best answer indicates: your class design is messed up, if you want to do that.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The solution depends on why you want to do it. If you want to be safe from future erroneous use of the class, I'd do:

```
class Parent(object):
    def hello(self):
        print 'Hello world'
    def goodbye(self):
        print 'Goodbye world'

class Child(Parent):
    def goodbye(self):
        raise NotImplementedError
```

This is explicit and you can include explanation in the exception message.

If you don't want to use a lot of methods from the parent class a better style would be to use composition instead of inheritance:

```
class Parent(object):
    def hello(self):
        print 'Hello world'
    def goodbye(self):
        print 'Goodbye world'

class Child:
    def __init__(self):
        self.buddy = Parent()
    def hello(self):
        return self.buddy.hello()
```

Answer (score 3):

```
class Child(Parent):
    def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        if attr == 'goodbye':
            raise AttributeError()
        return super(Child, self).__getattribute__(attr)
```

Comment: I dont need raise exception I just need that this method is missing

Comment: @Denis: please try to call an inexistant method on any object and see what happens (yes, an AttributeError is raised).

Answer (score 1):

This Python example shows how to design classes to achieve child class inheritance:

```
class HelloParent(object):

    def hello(self):
        print 'Hello world'

class Parent(HelloParent):
    def goodbye(self):
        print 'Goodbye world'


class Child(HelloParent):
    pass
```

Comment: This is a good solve but I cant change composition or use Mixin classes. Anyway +1

Comment: This is a good answer on design level, thanks for pointing it out.