# Structuring classes and inheritance in Python

Tags: python, class, oop, multiple-inheritance

Suppose I have the following structure:

```
class CasinoGame
    self.expected_return

class CardGame(CasinoGame)
    self.deck
    def shuffle()
    def reset() # get a new deck and shuffle

class Slot(CasinoGame)
    self.credits
    def spin()
    def reset() # return credit to user, reset bonus progression
```

Now I want to introduce another class `VideoPoker` which is a card-based slot game. Ideally I want to use methods and variables from both `CardGame`  and `Slot` classes. However, I'm hesitant to use the following structure (recombining tree?):

```
class VidPoker(CardGame, Slot)
```

I think it will be confusing to keep track of MRO  and inheritance structure especially when I need to add more classes later, extending depth and width.

Ideally I want VidPoker to inherit Slot (video poker is technically a slot machine), but "borrow" functions from  CardGame.

Is there any best practice, preferred way of structuring classes in these types of situation?

**EDIT**

A few folks suggested: [Is it possible to do partial inheritance with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647118/is-it-possible-to-do-partial-inheritance-with-python)

I think mixin method (accepted answer) would be a good solution most of the time, but it will fail in certain cases where method uses class variable.

Example

```
# this works
class Class2(object):
    def method(self):
        print ("I am method at %s" % self.__class__)

class Class1(object): pass

class Class0(Class1):
    method = Class2.method

ob = Class0()
ob.method()

# this doesn't work
class Class2(object):
    s = 'hi'
    def method(self):
        print (self.s)

class Class1(object): pass

class Class0(Class1):
    method = Class2.method

ob = Class0()
ob.method()
```

Back to my example, suppose `CardGame` has an immutable class variable `num_decks` used by `shuffle` method.  I wouldn't be able to call `shuffle` from `VidPoker` if it inherits `Slot`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647118/is-it-possible-to-do-partial-inheritance-with-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to do partial inheritance with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647118/is-it-possible-to-do-partial-inheritance-with-python)

Comment: You can try using a mixin https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin